# Token Mismatch error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to refresh myself with larval 5 since I haven't touched larval at all for over a year and Im running into a problem with the form token when submitting a form.

I doing everything (as far as I know) by the book and using best practises. The problem I am running into is when I submit my form I get a token mismatch error.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

I have look around the web and from what I can see Im doing everything I should be doing. Here is my form

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Articles</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{{ url('articles') }}">Back</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="row">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'articles']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Publish On:') !!}
        <!--{!! Form::date('date', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class' => 'form-control']); !!}-->
        {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Add Article', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']); !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>

@endsection
```

Here is the source code grabbed from the browser.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel/articles" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="wygz8Wm8tMAdTDxE5fSXkyJIWUVxorOU5xu2R66s">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" value="" id="title">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="body">Body:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" cols="50" rows="10" id="body"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="published_at">Publish On:</label>
    <!--<input class="form-control" name="date" type="date" value="2016-01-04">-->
    <input class="form-control" name="published_at" type="date" value="2016-01-04" id="published_at">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Add Article">
</div>

</form>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the handling route/controller. It shouldn't matter, but just want to confirm something

Comment: what version of laravel 5 ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Laravel 5? the Form:: facade hasn't been in Laravel since 4.

Comment: @JoeYes I'm using the latest version of Laravel 5. as far as the Form Facade I'm using the new Collective\Html\FormFacade

Comment: @Chris This is my route file
`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
 Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
 });

 Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
 Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticlesController@create');

 Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticlesController@show');

 Route::post('articles', 'ArticlesController@store');
});`

Comment: Controller: @chris
`class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    function index() {

     $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get();

     return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

    }

    function show($id) {

     $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

     //dd($article->published_at);

     return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }

    function store(Requests\CreateArticle $request) {


     Article::create($request->all());

     return redirect('articles');
    }
}`